# Webauthn securely store user credential data

Tags: google-chrome, safari, blob, hmac, webauthn

I am trying to add webauthn to my web app, and I want to securely store a private key with the credential data. The methods I have found for storing data with a credential are: hmac-secret extension, large blob extension, [CredentialsContainer.store()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CredentialsContainer/store) . Which, if any, of these methods can securely store data on/with the authenticator? Are there better ways of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CredentialsContainer.store` is not pertinent for public-key credentials: they are never stored, only created. (You can store other types of credentials, like passwords, but the title says "WebAuthn" so I'll stick to that topic.)

The `hmac-secret` extension (exposed as the [`prf`](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/#prf-extension) extension at the WebAuthn level) allows an arbitrary number of secrets to be derived using a PRF like HMAC. This is currently behind chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features but will have the greatest degree of support in security keys and will be supported by Android devices in the coming months. This is intended to be the answer to your question but is not fully ready yet.

The `credBlob` extension allows a small, fixed amount of data to be stored with a credential. It was not originally intended for secrets, however. Only newer security key will support this.

The `largeBlob` extension is for storing a KB or two of data with a credential, usually a certificate for that key. This will have the least security key support.

Probably none of those options currently work in Safari, however.

Comment: Hi this may be better suited to making a new question, but I'm wondering if you could provide a little more detail about credBlob and largeBlob. I want to store exactly 32 bytes of arbitrary data encrypted along with the non resident key data stored in the server during the fido registration ceremony. Is that what this extension does? Or does it require a resident key such that the data is actually stored in the authenticator?

Comment: credBlob allows for 32 bytes to be stored, although it may not work for non-discoverable credentials. (See https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.2-rd-20230321/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.2-rd-20230321.html#sctn-credBlob-extension)

largeBlob stores perhaps about a 1KB of data on a security key. It is for discoverable credentials (see https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.2-rd-20230321/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.2-rd-20230321.html#sctn-largeBlobKey-extension)

PRF derives keys for discoverable and non-discoverable credentials, but you need to encrypt with it.